# Live migrate local XenServer VM's not working - XenAPI

Tags: python, citrix, xen

I want to use python and the xenserver API to live migrate locally stored VM's, within a pool.

I am using the `xenapi.VM.Pool_Migrate($vm, $host, $options)` call and when I run it, the icon  for the `VM` in XenCenter turns yellow for a moment, and the script exits cleanly, but the `VM` does not move.

I think this is because the `VM` is locally stored on the host. But I can manually migrate it to another host within XenCenter, so how do I do this in the API?

Comment: Just one question , are you using the enterprise edition ?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

Get the `vm_ref` and `new_vm_host_ref`

```
vm_ref = xenapi.VM.get_by_uuid(vm_uuid)
```

Now migrate with the live migration flag set as true

```
xenapi.VM.pool_migrate(vm_ref, new_vm_host_ref, {"live": "true"})
```

Though Xenserver is now free but the previous releases supports live migration only for the enterprise edition.

Comment: Are your VM's datastores local to the XenServer hosts, or on shared storage?

Comment: First of all live migration or Xenmotion is possible only in shared storage environment. Because host1's local storage is not accessible by host2. 

Second thing is , it is the running state which is being transferred, not the entire contents of the VM.

Third is, source and destination hosts should have a compatible CPU instruction set.