# XenServer: VDI not available when migrating a vm

Tags: migration, live, citrix

I have four identical Hosts with Citrix XenServer 6.2.
Lets name them host1-4
All Updates are installed.

I want to live migrate a vm from `host1` to `host2`.
When I start the migration process, it directly abort with error: `The VDI is not available`
If I move it from `host1` to `host3/4`, it works. So it should be a problem with `host2`.

Anyone have an idea?
Which log files are important to search trough?

Edit:

Here are the errors from the console:

```
SR_BACKEND_FAILURE_46
Error parameters: , The VDI is not available [opterr=Error scanning VDI 902b8db7
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a problem with shared storage. Double check your shared storage is properly connected or not. I used to face this problem when my iSCSI server got down for some reason. But remember Xencenter may show the storage as connected. So go to the storage server and restart it. Then forget the storage and reattach it again from Xencenter.

If this doesn't work then check this [link](http://ingenious-excerpts.blogspot.in/2012/05/xenserver-and-vdi-is-not-available.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using the local storage for my VM's. I think, it's not possible to reconnect the local storage, right? I also rebooted both hosts. No change.

Comment: Yes, migration not possible with localstorage. Check my comment in the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533380/live-migrate-local-xenserver-vms-not-working-xenapi/21549941#comment32590625_21549941

Comment: Now, I'm confused :S. host1-4 are exactly the same (except hostname/ip). So all hosts are using the local storage. And I already moved VM's to a other host and it worked.. It's only one host, which fails..

Comment: Move is different and Migration is different.Migration is the running state which is being transferred, not the entire contents of the VM. So your VM will be in same storage but the VM will be provisioned in different host. This is possible when both host has a shared storage.

Comment: At the wizard, I choosed the storage repository of the destination host. So the entire VM is being transferred to the new host. After the migration is completed, the VM disappears from the source host and is showed at the destination host. I used the following command: `xe vm-migrate remote-master=destination_host remote-username=root remote-password=my_password vm=VirtualServerName live=true force=true`